# Joining and grouping multiple tables with LINQ when using a linking table

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I'm looking for some advice on how best to get the first record when using a join with multiple tables, as demonstrated below.

I have three tables:

- Leads <-- this should be unique in the results
- LeadAddresses (joining
  table)
- Addresses

Normally I'd join them like this:

```
from t2
    in db.Leads
    .Where(o => t1.LeadId == o.Lead_ID)
from t4
    in db.LeadAddresses
    .Where(o => t2.Lead_ID == o.Lead_ID)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
from t5
    in db.Addresses
    .Where(o => t4.Address_ID == o.Address_ID)
    .DefaultIfEmpty()
```

(if this is bad practice, let me know ;)

I'm looking to get a property from the **Addresses** table (the one with, say, the maximum ID) for each **Lead** record and project to a model:

```
select new LeadGridModel
        {
            ...
        });
```

Example:

```
Lead Company | City    | ZIP
==============================
Company 1    | Boston  | 00000
Company 2    | Houston | 00001
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
from l in db.Leads
from a in l.LeadAddresses.Select(la => la.Address).OrderByDescending(a => a.ID).Take(1).DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { l, a }
```

This might look tricky, but you understand it part by part:

1. Using `OrderByDescending` in combination with `Take(1)` we take the address with the maximum ID
2. Using DefaultIfEmpty we create a left-join.

Be aware that this pattern forces a loop-join due to limitation of SQL Server. For small result sets this is usually not a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The problem in this case is that the objects do not have relationships in the database, which is why I'm joining them manually. In this instance, I am unable to create these relationships.

Comment: @Nick - Just replace the *Select* with your *Where*

Comment: Just replace "l.LeadAddresses" with "db.LeadAddresses.Where(la => la.LeadID == l.ID)" and similar for the address navigation property.